# conditional replacement of rows with a number

Tags: python, perl, bioinformatics

I have a big file containing 27 columns and nearly 6 million rows. The following is a little example of my file

```
head data
0.65   0.722222   1.0      0.75     0
0.35   0.277778   0.0      0.25     0
0      0.666667   0.75     0.5      0.5625
0      0.333333   0.25     0.5      0.4375
```

Rows are samples, and I have "2 rows per sample" (one for observation "a", and the other observation "b"). In the example above I showed data for 2 samples (rows 1 and 2 correspond to sample1 and rows 3 and 4 correspond to sample 2). I want to check if for each sample, both observations are 0, replace them with 9.
this is my desired output:

```
head desired
0.65   0.722222   1.0      0.75     9
0.35   0.277778   0.0      0.25     9
9      0.666667   0.75     0.5      0.5625
9      0.333333   0.25     0.5      0.4375
```

Any perl or python or bash (if reliable for such a big file )solution how to do it? 
In the past I was just splitting the file for each sample and running the following code for each file

```
awk 'NR==1 { split($0,a);next;} NR==2 {split($0,b);for(i=1;i<= NF;i++) printf("%s%s",(i==1?"":"\t"),a[i]==0 && b[i]==0?9:a[i]);
printf("\n");;for(i=1;i<= NF;i++) printf("%s%s",(i==1?"":"\t"),a[i]==0 && b[i]==0?9:b[i]);printf("\n");} '
```

but now I want to do it for the entire file, do not want to split it.

Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: what if one row within a pair of SNP contains `0` population and the other doesn't ? what should be the output?

Comment: @Jesse_b, thanks for the comment, agree. I just edited  my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

firstLineZero = False

# Open the file for reading
with open("biodata2", "r") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        # Check if last value in line is 0
        if not firstLineZero and line.split()[-1] == "0":
            # Save this line, and set a boolean
            firstLineZero = True
            prevLine = line
        elif firstLineZero and line.split()[-1] == "0":
            # Now we know that both lines end with 0.
            # Change the final value to 9 in both lines...
            prevLineSplit = prevLine.split()
            thisLineSplit = line.split()
            prevLineSplit[-1] = "9" 
            thisLineSplit[-1] = "9" 
            prevLine = "\t".join(prevLineSplit)
            thisLine = "\t".join(thisLineSplit)
            print(prevLine)
            print(thisLine)
            # Reset boolean
            firstLineZero = False
            # Reset prevLine
            prevLine = ""
        else:
            print(line, end="")

# If we have a 'trailing' saved line, print that
if prevLine is not None:
    print(prevLine, end="")
```

Execution example, with a couple of more lines to provide a POC.

Data:

```
cat biodata2 
0.65    0.722222    1.0     0.75    0
0.35    0.277778    0.0     0.25    0
0       0.666667    0.75    0.5     0.5625
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     0.4375
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     1
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     0
```

Execution:

```
./readBioData.py
0.65    0.722222    1.0     0.75    9
0.35    0.277778    0.0     0.25    9
0       0.666667    0.75    0.5     0.5625
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     0.4375
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     1
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     0
```

Obviously, if you want to save this to a file instead of printing to `stdout`, you will have to alter the `print` statements into `write` and set a file for writing.

Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

firstLineZero = False
outFile = open("bioDataOut.txt", "w")

# Open the file for reading
with open("biodata2", "r") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        # Check if last value in line is 0
        if not firstLineZero and line.split()[-1] == "0":
            # Save this line, and set a boolean
            firstLineZero = True
            prevLine = line
        elif firstLineZero and line.split()[-1] == "0":
            # Now we know that both lines end with 0.
            # Change the final value to 9 in both lines...
            prevLineSplit = prevLine.split()
            thisLineSplit = line.split()
            prevLineSplit[-1] = "9" 
            thisLineSplit[-1] = "9" 
            prevLine = "\t".join(prevLineSplit)
            thisLine = "\t".join(thisLineSplit)
            outFile.write(prevLine + "\n")
            outFile.write(thisLine + "\n")
            # Reset boolean
            firstLineZero = False
            # Reset prevLine
            prevLine = ""
        else:
            outFile.write(line)

# If we have a 'trailing' saved line, print that
if prevLine is not None:
    outFile.write(prevLine)

outFile.close()
```

Then you can do:

```
./readBioDataSaveToFile.py
cat bioDataOut.txt 
0.65    0.722222    1.0     0.75    9
0.35    0.277778    0.0     0.25    9
0       0.666667    0.75    0.5     0.5625
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     0.4375
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     1
0       0.333333    0.25    0.5     0
```

Answer (score -1):

The trick to handle pairs of lines is to merge them:

```
paste - - < paired_file
```

Then you can test/manipulate the fields with awk (`$1==0 && $6==0`, etc.)

Comment: ,this is not an answer, it could be better just to suggest your view as a comment here!